# How can I deal with dictionary-like data for classification？

Tags: classification, feature-engineering

Recently I got an interesting dataset, it looks like this:

| user   | ip_set               | label|

| user1 | {ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4}    | 0    |

| user2 | {ip1,ip2...}         | 1    |

The purpose is to classify user using ip_set, but I don't know how to extract features from it. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: ip_set for each user may have different size, and ips are unique.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of unique ip addresses are very large, you can use Matrix factorization method. Represent the users as rows and ip addresses as the column of the matrix M. Each matrix entry $m_{ij}$ represents whether the user i has visited the ip j or not. Now apply the SVD decomposition on this.

$A = UDV^T$

Now the rows of the matrix U represents the user.

Now you can apply any clustering method to classify the users.

Comment: You mean one-hot encoding? But the dataset is too large, and the matrix will be 150,000 x 150,000. I cannot read the data into ram...

Comment: this link will help you in that  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/how-to-do-svd-and-pca-with-big-data

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possibility based on the data that you provided: You can treat the IPs similar to bag of words model. For example, let us say that number of unique IPs are N. Then, each user's feature representation can be an N dimensional vector with entries set to 1 if the user had the particular IP mapped otherwise 0. For example, if user 1 browsed IP 1-4, their representation will be [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, ..., 0]. Additionally, you can add some aggregate features like # of unique IPs for each user.

Since the number of unique IPs is large, you may have to think about handling the large size using some trick. But it is not possible to elaborate on this given the limited information about the problem.